# UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION error code using square web api with android

Tags: square-connect

Starting a transaction using Square web api(Android) returns on given WEB_CALLBACK_URI with `error_code` as `UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION` and `error_description` as "The installed version of square point of sales is too old. It doesn't support this version of the point of sale SDK"

I installed the latest Square app Version=4.57

I used the following code on my html page

```
<a  href="intent:#Intent;
action=com.squareup.register.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;
S.browser_fallback_url=http://08e71683.ngrok.io;
S.com.squareup.register.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=http://08e71683.ngrok.io/abc;
S.com.squareup.register.CLIENT_ID=sandbox-sq0idp-6Lo2W9zX8K9b08zKxmfUtw;
S.com.squareup.register.API_VERSION=v2;
i.com.squareup.register.TOTAL_AMOUNT=100;
S.com.squareup.register.CURRENCY_CODE=USD;
S.com.squareup.register.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.register.TENDER_CARD,com.squareup.register.TENDER_CARD_ON_FILE,com.squareup.register.TENDER_CASH,com.squareup.register.TENDER_OTHER;
end">
 Send me $
</a>
```

I tried a lot in finding solution on google but couldn't find it. I hope there would be someone for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are trying to use a nonexistent version of of the Point of Sale API. Chagne `S.com.squareup.register.API_VERSION=v2;` to `S.com.squareup.register.API_VERSION=v1.3;`and see if you have success.

Comment: i tried changing the version to v1.3 as well. This time the response was "The client id parameter is a sandbox id. Sandbox IDs are not supported in register api. Please use a production client id".

But what would be the way to develop integration using sandbox account?

Comment: Right now you can't use the Register API in a sandbox environment. If you want to test things out, just make cash transactions or make transactions of any type and just refund them.